# Font Awesome icon not display on IE9 compatibility view

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-9, ie-compatibility-mode

In a project I have use font Awesome icon to display icon in default format like . It's working fine on Chrome, FireFox and IE9 & IE11 but not display on compatibility view.

I have used meta tag to force render the document but its not working. Also when in compatibility view some css look not like standard view as other browser.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
```

Actually, my page generate through 'xsl' template thats why I also used htm5 JS as follows -

```
<xsl:comment>
<![CDATA[[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="js/jquery/html5shiv.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="js/jquery/respond.js" type="text/javascript" />
<![endif]]]>
</xsl:comment>
```

And here is my HTML structure in IE9 Campatibility mode -

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-16" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/picdef.css?ver=T1.0" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.css?ver=T1.0" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/print.css?ver=T1.0" media="print">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=T1.0" media="screen">
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="images/favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
 ..................................
</body>
</html>
```

I found in DOM that html5 js not loaded.

Any solution? sorry for bad english.

Comment: any suggestion for any expart?

Answer (score 1):

Your compatibility mode settings are telling IE to use IE7-compatibility mode.

Please note that Font Awesome does not work in IE7 (nor in IE7-compatibility mode), because IE7 lacks support for several key features that Font Awesome uses.

Even IE8 support is poor in Font Awesome. Ideally you should only consider supporting IE9 and higher.

So your best option is to drop compatibility mode. Change your meta tag like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

... that is, remove the `IE=9; IE=8; IE=7;`.

If you really do need your site to support IE7 and IE8 then you will need to re-think your site design, and use older techniques to create it.

Comment: I need only FontAswame work on IE9 & IE11 compatibility mode. Some of other look and feel also not so good on that mode. It's okey but I need to display FontAwesome on compatibility mode of IE9 & IE11. @ Spudley

Comment: IE has many compatibility modes. There is a compatibility mode for each version from 7 up to the version you're running. So IE9 has compat modes for IE7 and 8. And IE11 has compat modes for IE7, 8,9 and 10. The lower modes will make the browser pretend to be IE7 or IE8. If you use those modes, then you can't use software that doesn't work in IE7 or IE8. Do you really need to use the compat modes? It doesn't sound like you really understand what they actually do.

Comment: Yes IE having many compatibility mode and I force document type to IE9 and IE11 latest (available) version using meta tag <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9, IE=edge" /> but Font  Font Awesome not working on both version. Thanks for reply.

Comment: In browser Developer tools I see that document mode render to IE9 in IE9 compatibility mode.

Comment: I need to support IE9 and IE11 compatibility mode.